# regarding adding zero if null value find in while array

Tags: php, mysql

I have and problem in adding ''(blank) value instead of zero inside while. I have put if condition if any null value find, it will add ""(blank) instead zero. but it is not giving me the blank. I am arranging while condition as according to the pivot query as:

```
SELECT employee_name,employee_image,grade_date,grade_id
    ,(CASE WHEN day = 'Monday' 
                       THEN grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Monday
    ,(CASE WHEN day = 'Tuesday' 
                       THEN grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Tuesday
    ,(CASE WHEN day = 'Wednesday' 
                       THEN grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Wednesday
    ,(CASE WHEN day = 'Thursday' 
                       THEN grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Thursday
    ,(CASE WHEN day = 'Friday' 
                       THEN grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Friday
    ,(CASE WHEN day = 'Saturday' 
                       THEN grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Saturday
    ,(CASE WHEN day = 'Sunday' 
                       THEN grade_marks ELSE NULL END) AS Sunday
FROM grade WHERE employee_name='".$_SESSION['agent']."' LIMIT ".$start_from.",".$per_page
```

My while condition:

```
<?php if($select_fetch['Monday'] == '') { ?>
       <td><p class="monday text-center margin_35 marks_background"><?php echo "-"; ?></p></td>
<?php } else { ?>

       <td><p class="monday text-center margin_35 marks_background"><?php echo $select_fetch['Monday']; ?></p></td>
<?php } ?>
```

at the top with jquery i am replacing value of "-" with zero for adding the colums value as:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".monday").each(function() {
            if ($.trim($(this).html()) == '-') {
                    $(this).html("0");
            } else {}
     }
 });
```

After that when i refresh the page the "-" is embed until the page load. after that it adds zero as it is. i think it just because of the assignment of `$(this).htm("0")`. But i want the total of column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:::::::::::::::::: UPDATE ::::::::::::::::::

Try this isset() :

```
<td><p class="monday text-center margin_35 marks_background"><?php echo isset(trim($select_fetch['Monday'])) ?  $select_fetch['Monday'] : "0"; ?></p></td>
```

Try this solution :

I think the inside if, current refrence is getting changed. Try this code.

```
    monday_store = 0;
    $(".monday").each(function() {
       $custThis = $(this);
        if ($.trim($(this).html()) == '-') {
            $custThis.html("0");
        } else {}
        monday_store = (parseFloat(monday_store) + parseFloat($(this).html())).toFixed(1);
    }); //here assign the value -- 
    $("#monday").html(monday_store);
```

Comment: `empty(trim(` would generate error on older versions of php. `Cannot use empty with return values .....`

Comment: I was thinking that there may be issue of blank space that's why your is condition is getting satisfied..

Comment: ohh..no you can do this just `trim` it first then check with `empty`

Comment: this condition works fine.. but at the top i am doing total of the colums value. so if " echo isset(trim($select_fetch['Monday'])) ?  $select_fetch['Monday'] : "-"; ?></p>".. "-" is find inside the class i am using the replace with "0" there. but it again embed "0" inside while at that place. how can i solve this problem.?

Comment: if($.trim($(this).html()) == '-')
//           {
//               $(this).html("0");
//           }
//           else
//           {
//               
//           }

Comment: Not getting what you are trying to say...please update your question for more details with your code.

Comment: $(".monday").each(function() {
//           if($.trim($(this).html()) == '-')
//           {
//               $(this).html("0");
//           }
//           else
//           {
//               
//           } 
           monday_store=(parseFloat(monday_store)+parseFloat($(this).html())).toFixed(1);
           
        });
       here assign the value -- $("#monday").html(monday_store);

Comment: thnx for ur help.. but i am already using like this as declare  monday_store = 0; but the result are same. any other way please..?

Comment: when the control enters into the $(.monday).each. it firstly check that the condition one by one and after that set the value default to the zero. problem occurs there..

Comment: pankaj do u have skypee id or any where i can show you.?

Answer (score 1):

Try with  `empty()` -

```
if(empty($select_fetch['Monday'])) {...}
```

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: and thanx for ur reply..any other way .?

Answer (score 0):

Try below one:

```
<td><p class="monday text-center margin_35 marks_background">
<?php echo (is_null($select_fetch['Monday']))?"":$select_fetch['Monday']; ?>
</p></td>
```